# Scale a RectF based the aspect ratio of the bitmap's original dimensions which is used as texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, aspect-ratio

I have a RectF(A) in Android and I'm drawing another rectangle(B) inside the outer RectF(A). How can scale RectF(B) based on the aspect ratio of the texture (bitmap)'s original dimensions?

Image : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdm3h.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to place a scaled rect inside another rect you have 2 possibilities, fit and fill. The first one will leave some uncovered borders while the second will fill the whole rect but some parts of the rect will not be visible (outside the rect). In both cases one of the dimensions of rect B will be the same as the target area, which of them depends on comparing the ratios of the 2 rects and "fit" or "fill" mode.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
float pannelWidth, pannelHeight;
float imageWidth, imageHeight;

float pannelRatio = pannelWidth/pannelHeight;
float imageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight;

float outputWidth, outputHeight;

bool useFit = true;//set whatever

if(pannelRatio > imageRatio) {
    if(useFit) {
        //fit in width (width scale is 1.0)
        outputWidth = pannelWidth;
        outputHeight = pannelWidth*(imageHeight/imageWidth);
    }
    else {
        //fill in height (height scale is 1.0)
        outputWidth = pannelHeight*(imageWidth/imageHeight);
        outputHeight = pannelHeight;
    }

}
else if(pannelRatio < imageRatio) {
    if(useFit) {
        //fit in height (height scale is 1.0)
        outputWidth = pannelHeight*(imageWidth/imageHeight);
        outputHeight = pannelHeight;
    }
    else {
        //fill in width (width scale is 1.0)
        outputWidth = pannelWidth;
        outputHeight = pannelWidth*(imageHeight/imageWidth);
    }
}
else {
    outputWidth = pannelWidth;
    outputHeight = pannelHeight;
}
```